# Problem: Remote connection with pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, centos, pgadmin-4

I just installed the Java and PostgreSQL environment on a server (for remote testing) CentOS 7

From the command line using ssh would seem that there are no problems in the sense that I can access the user "postgres"

But when I try to access to PostgreSQL via PgAdmin4 I get an error, or get

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "81.xxx.2.xx" and accepting
TCP / IP connections on port 5433?
```

I thought it was the firewall so I typed

```
firewall-cmd = public --zone --add-port = 5432 / tcp --permanent
```

but my server get

```
FirewallD is not running
```

Any idea to solve the problem ????